# Cannot include "javaee-api-7.0.jar" in Android Application

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

When I try to run my Android Application and I include the "javaee-api-7.0.jar" in my libs folder, I get the following error at compilation time:

```
[2014-04-22 11:27:53 - firstApp] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/management/j2ee/ListenerRegistration.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2014-04-22 11:27:53 - firstApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-04-22 11:27:53 - firstApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You cannot create nor even deploy Java EE applications in an Android device. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse)",  `javaee-api-7.0.jar` is a core library, please read your full error message to see what you can do to avoid it

Comment: My android app has a REST Client to connect to a Web Server. I am using `javax.ws.rs` libs and `javax.json` libs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I removed the jar and added the individual libs but on starting the app I saw that I require a lot of javax libs such as `javax.inject` and `javax.annotation` and `javax.xml` in addition to the ones I mentioned above.

If I do require more `javax` libs, do I have to download all of them individually? Why can't I just include the `javaee-7` jar and have it all?

Comment: You're following the wrong approach. You just need the specific libraries for the job, you don't need to add a Java EE 7 library to your application, unless you want that the android device runs out the battery really fast :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I was getting that `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory` not found error. But when I added the `jsr173-1.0.jar`, I got the same error as in the question. What do I do?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but this time it was with the class `javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class`.

Comment: Having the same problem, because I'm using [`grpc`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) whose `grpc-auth` subpackage depends on `javaee-api`. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, as @LuiggiMendoza, suggested is not to use the whole `javaee-api` library, but individual jars of components which are required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `javax.management.*` is not available in the [current set of APIs offered by the Android platform](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). That means it's safe to suppress the warning... for now. But if Android ever decides to add this class, there will be trouble.

In my case, however, `javaee-api` was being required but did not seem to be actually used, so I could just suppress this dependency as follows (syntax taken from [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119)):

```
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-all:0.7.1") {
      exclude group: "javax"
    }
```

If you do actually need something from the `javaee-api` package, you should use JarJar to rename it, as suggested by the error message. The [jarjar-gradle](https://github.com/vRallev/jarjar-gradle) plugin would come in useful here.